# Remove non common items between two arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function to remove non common elements between two arrays in javascript but the issue is my code reduces some items in the array and increases some. Below is my code

```js
function canFormPairs(cleanSocks, dirtySocks) {
  let compared = [];
  cleanSocks.forEach(item => {
    dirtySocks.forEach(dItem => {
      if (item == dItem) {
        compared.push(item);
      }
    });
  });
  return compared;
}
console.log(canFormPairs([1, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 56], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78]));
```

The above code gives

```
[ 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5 ]
```

Instead of the desired result of

```
[1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]
```

When sorted

Please what is the issue with this code

Comment: You are right but thats not the problem here

Comment: I'm just trying to understand if there is anything that I do not understand, before I can jump to answer

Comment: Alrigth. Would edit

Comment: Would read on set now. Thanks. But what is the issue with this algorithm

Comment: Does position matter? Does it matter if left set has 2 fives and right set has 1 five?

Answer (score 7):

Your current logic pushes the item for every *unique index match* between the two arrays. For example, with 7, 7 gets matched at index 3 (first array) and index 3 (second array), so it gets pushed once. Then, the next match is with index 3 (first array) and index 7 (second array). There are no more *index* matches other than `3-3` and `3-7`, so only two `7` (values) get pushed.

I'd consider making a `Set` from both arrays, then combining both arrays and using `.filter` to remove elements not in both sets, and then sort the array:

```js
function canFormPairs(a, b) {
  const setA = new Set(a);
  const setB = new Set(b);
  return [...a, ...b]
    .filter(item => setA.has(item) && setB.has(item))
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
console.log(canFormPairs([1, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 56], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
function canFormPairs(cleanSocks, dirtySocks) {
  let compared = [];
  let one = cleanSocks.filter(el => dirtySocks.includes(el));
  let two = dirtySocks.filter(el => cleanSocks.includes(el));
  compared = one.concat(two);
  compared.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  return compared;
}
console.log(canFormPairs([1, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 56], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping this answer focused on *why OP's code gives incorrect result*.

Your algo reads like,

- Having 2 arrays, `a`, `b`
- Loop on `a`.
- Loop on `b`.
- If `a[i] === b[i]`, push `a[i]` to result.

**Issue:**

- You will have `m*n` items in result array. So for `1`, since both have once only, you have it only 1 time. Similarly for `5`, its `2*3` hence you get `6` times instead of `5`. Output should be `m+n instead`.
- Both the array can have duplicates and are not sorted. So final result will not be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your function and it works now:

```
function canFormPairs(cleanSocks, dirtySocks) {
    let compared = [];
    let cleanSocksUniqueItems = [];
    cleanSocks.map((item, index) => {
        cleanSocks.slice(index+1).map(elem => {
            if (item === elem && !cleanSocks.slice(0, index).includes(item)) {
               dirtySocks = [...dirtySocks, elem];
            }
        });
    });
    cleanSocksUniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(cleanSocks));
    cleanSocksUniqueItems.forEach(item => {
        dirtySocks.forEach(dItem => {
            if (item === dItem) {
                if (!compared.includes(item)) {
                    compared = [...compared, item];
                }
                compared = [...compared, item];
            }
        });
   });
   return compared.sort();
}
console.log(canFormPairs([1, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 56], [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using `flatMap`, have a look.

```js
Array.prototype.pairs = function(arr2){
var arr1= this;
let compared = [arr1, arr2].flatMap(function (x)
{
  return x.filter(a=> arr1.indexOf(a) != -1 && arr2.indexOf(a) != -1)
}).sort((a,b)=> a-b);

return compared
}

var res = [1, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 56].pairs([1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 78])
console.log(res);
```